# Java, Разделение массива на положительные и отрицательные числа

Tags: java, массивы, инспекция-кода, коллекции

> Write a C program for:
>
> - Loading an array v of DIM (DIM is a constant) integer numbers.
> - Copying all its positive elements into an array named vp and all its negative ones into another array named vn.
> - Displaying the contents of vp and vn (only the values copied from v).
>
> Example: let DIM = 10 and assume that the following array has been
>   introduced:
>
> v = [18 11 -4 5 0 0 -2 3 25 0]
>
> Then, the following two arrays must be generated and displayed:
>
> vp = [18 11 5 3 25]
>
> vn = [-4 -2]

1. Нуждаюсь в вашей оценке
2. Можно ли сделать проще?
3. Какие советы можете дать начинающему смотря на мой код?
4. Всем спасибо заранее :), пока вы смотрите этот код, я делаю след задание)

Я сделал это так:

```
public static void lab1() {
    int[] arr1 = {5, -2, 4, 10, -22, 35, -14, 45};
    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length ; i++) {
        if(arr1[i] > 0){
            pos++;
        }else{
            neg++;
        }
    }
    int[] arrpos = new int[pos];
    int[] arrneg = new int[neg];
    int countpos = 0;
    int countneg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length ; i++) {
        if(arr1[i] > 0){
            arrpos[countpos] = arr1[i];
            countpos++;
        }else{
            arrneg[countneg] = arr1[i];
            countneg++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrneg.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrneg[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrpos.length ; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrpos[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

До кучи вариант на стримах:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr1 = {5, -2, 4, 10, -22, 35, -14, 45};
        Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> res = Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed()
            .filter(x -> x != 0)
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x > 0));
        System.out.println(res.get(true));
        System.out.println(res.get(false));
    }
}
```

Учтите:

1. Данное решение будет работать на `Java` не менее 8-ой версии
2. Строго говоря это хоть и однострочное, но не самое производительное решение
3. Результат будет лежать не в двух массивах, а мапке, но это решаемо

Кстати, согласно примеру, надо было еще вырезать нули :)

Answer (score 0):

Советы:

- `for` замените на `foreach`:

  Было:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length ; i++) {
  ```

  Станет:

  ```
  for (int i : arr1) {
  ```
- Вместо использования цикла для вывода элементов, используйте `Arrays.toString`:

  Было:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < arrneg.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(arrneg[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < arrpos.length ; i++) {
      System.out.println(arrpos[i]);
  }
  ```

  Станет:

  ```
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrneg));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrpos));
  ```
- В вопросе упоминается сортировка, поэтому решил тоже ее упоминуть. Для сортировки используйте метод `Arrays.sort`:

  ```
  int[] arr1 = {5, -2, 4, 10, -22, 35, -14, 45};
  Arrays.sort(arr1);
  ...
  ```

---

Получится такой код:

```
int[] arr1 = {5, -2, 4, 10, -22, 35, -14, 45};
int pos = 0;
int neg = 0;
for (int x : arr1) {
    if (x > 0) {
        pos++;
    } else {
        neg++;
    }
}

int[] arrpos = new int[pos];
int[] arrneg = new int[neg];

int countpos = 0;
int countneg = 0;
for (int x : arr1) {
    if (x > 0) {
        arrpos[countpos] = x;
        countpos++;
    } else {
        arrneg[countneg] = x;
        countneg++;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrneg));  // [-2, -22, -14]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrpos));  // [5, 4, 10, 35, 45]
```

Comment: "Сортировка" в заголовке употребляется в смысле "разделение". Из текста задачи видно и из примера видно, что сортировать ничего не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть так же вариант на Stream API:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[] arr = {5, -2, 4, 10, -22, 35, -14, 45};
        int[] index = {0};
        List<Integer> sortedNumbers = Arrays.stream(arr)
                .sorted()
                .peek(number -> {
                    if (number < 0) {
                        index[0]++;
                    }
                }).boxed()
                .collect(toList());
        System.out.println(sortedNumbers.subList(0, index[0]));
        System.out.println(sortedNumbers.subList(index[0], sortedNumbers.size()));
    }

}
```